# Compass Blueprint Liquid starting point

Tags: css, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I'm trying to move to a liquid grid using the compass/blueprint/liquid (http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/liquid/) however Im getting stuck with the very basic stuff.

Can someone point me to a set of template files which I can use to start out with i.e containing the right includes and settings for a liquid layout?

Answer (score 3):

why not use [susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) for as the grid system? It's better integrated in compass and designed specifically for liquid layouts. Also, you can still use blueprint for other things, just exclude the grid.

```
sudo gem install compass-susy-plugin
compass create myproject -r susy -u susy
```